# React - How to set default value in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I used [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) in my application for showing select box. below is code of my select.

```
<Select
       className="custom-form-control mb-2"
       name="organization_options"
       options={this.organizationOptions()}
       placeholder={false}
       onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
       value={selectedValue === "" ? this.organizationOptions()[0] : selectedValue}
/>
```

Below are the options i already have in select box

```
0: {value: "62", label: "Dfdf"}
1: {value: "128", label: "Dfdfdsf"}
2: {value: "151", label: "Fgfdgdfh"}
3: {value: "121", label: "Hhhfas"}
4: {value: "55", label: "My Sensor_56"}
5: {value: "13", label: "New Org"}
6: {value: "44", label: "Org 2"}
7: {value: "148", label: "Testing App"}
```

I have the value from query string like value="55", if the value is present i want to show that selected value in select box .

I tried in 2 different ways which are shown as below code ,

**1)**

```
selectedValue='55'
defaultValue={this.organizationOptions().find(op => {
   return op.value === selectedValue
})}
```

**2**

```
defaultValue={{value: "55", label: "My Sensor_56"}}
```

But no one works, Can somebody tell me How can i set defaultV
alue if already have or don't show default value if i don't have selected value ?

Comment: what version are you using

Comment: ` "react-select": "^2.0.0"`

Comment: `defaultValue` should be `55` only in your case. As defaultValue is selected option.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra I already tried this like defaultValue="55", its not working . react-select taking whole object as option, like this `{value: "55", label: "My Sensor_56"}` .

Comment: I tried an example with react-select `value={{value: "55", label: "My Sensor_56"}}` working well for me,

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Can you show me code what you written ?

Comment: @Damien did you even check my question, i used different library https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select and the question you flaged duplicate its pure in react. don't flag until you have proper knowledge about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here default value we are finding out in organization options and pass it as value in Select:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  organizationOptions = () => {
    return [
       {value: "62", label: "Dfdf"},
       {value: "128", label: "Dfdfdsf"},
       {value: "151", label: "Fgfdgdfh"},
       {value: "121", label: "Hhhfas"},
       {value: "55", label: "My Sensor_56"},
       {value: "13", label: "New Org"},
       {value: "44", label: "Org 2"},
      {value: "148", label: "Testing App"}
    ]
  }

  render() {
    const selectedValue = "55"
    return (
      <Select
        value={this.organizationOptions().find(op => {
           return op.value === selectedValue
        })}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={this.organizationOptions()}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is it your answer ? like as you mentioned in answer its already working . i want to know how to set default value

Comment: This is the example working for me . to set default value `value={ this.organizationOptions()[1] }`

Comment: Welcome @Vishal

Comment: @PardeepDhingra what if you want to set the default value as what you have typed in and it's not present in the option array . How do you go about that?

Comment: Does this set the selected label as well?

Comment: How do you set a defaultValue if the selectedValue = ["1","2"]